# Regex filter out what's inside { }

Tags: regex, notepad++

From a record:

```
ERR_KEY_VALUE=Error logging id = {0,number,integer}; patient email = {1};
```

and similar records, I need to select everything that is:
1. after first '='
2. not { } and not inside { }

Therefore:

ERR_KEY_VALUE=**Error logging id =** {0,number,integer}; **patient email =** {1}**;**

I got this, but doesn't work:

```
=.*(^[{*}])
```

EDIT:

```
STATUS_INVITE_SENT=Invite sent
STATUS_IN_PROGRESS=In Progress
STATUS_COMPLETE=Complete
WEBUSER_DUPLICATE=An account with username ''{0}'' already exists
FAMILY_TABLE_FIELD_MISSING=The First Name field 
DD_VALUE_AND=AND
KEY_VALUE=OR
family=family
ERR_KEY_VALUE=Error logging id = {0,number,integer}; patient email = {1};
```

result:

...so after using my regex in Notepad++ i will replace selected text with ***

```
STATUS_INVITE_SENT=***
STATUS_IN_PROGRESS=***
STATUS_COMPLETE=***
WEBUSER_DUPLICATE=*** ''{0}'' ***
FAMILY_TABLE_FIELD_MISSING=***
DD_VALUE_AND=***
KEY_VALUE=***
family=***
ERR_KEY_VALUE=*** {0,number,integer}; *** {1};
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using with your regex?

Comment: What do you need exactly? Extract those substrings? Split on `^[^=]*=|{[^{}]*};`. Or try to capture them with `([^=]*)=(?=\s*{[^{}]*};)` or just `([^=]*)=\s*{[^{}]*};`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just need to replace what's filtered out in Notepad++.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm testing with regexr.com and seems not to work.

Comment: Then try using Wiktor's regex patterns.

Comment: Well, `=.*(^[{*}])` is doomed to fail since `^` matches the start of a string. Unless you are using ECMAScript 2018 compatible regex engine and use `s` modifier, `.` won't match a newline, and that pattern can't work. Please clarify where this regex will be used, and please share the related code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , I have txt files with keys and values, like:

`ERR_DUPLICATE=An account with username ''{0}'' already exists
ERR_MATCH_PROBAND=The email address you entered does not match the email address associated with this. Please use the email address where you received your invitation to continue.
ERR_PASSCODE_DOESNT_MATCH_USER=This is not correct Passcode for given user.`


Need to replace all values with ***, just leaving {} and what's inside.  For this purpose I'm using Notepad++ search/replace, which accepts regex.

Comment: Please add the sample lines with expected output to the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^[^=\n]*=)\K(?:(\h*'*\{[^{}]*\}'*;?\h*)|(?:(?!\h*'*\{[^{}]*\}'*;?\h*).)+)
```

and replace with

```
(?{1}$1:***)
```

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^[^=\n]*=)` - either the start of the next match (`\G(?!^)`) or the start of a line, then any 0+ chars other than `=` and a newline, and then a `=` (`^[^=\n]*=`)
- `\K` - omit the whole text matched so far
- `(?:(\h*'*\{[^{}]*\}'*;?\h*)|(?:(?!\h*'*\{[^{}]*\}'*;?\h*).)+)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `(\h*'*\{[^{}]*\}'*;?\h*)`: Capturing group 1 matching...
  - `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
  - `'*` - 0+ single quotes
  - `\{[^{}]*\}`
  - `'*` - 0+ single quotes
  - `;?` - an optional `;`
  - `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:(?!\h*'*\{[^{}]*\}'*;?\h*).)+` - any char, 1 or more repetitions, that do not start the sequence (see above).

The `(?{1}$1:***)` replacement replaces the match with the contents of Group 1 if it matches, else replaces with `***`.

See the screenshot:

[image]